# Session expire design pattern

Tags: ios, authentication

I have often had to cope with sessions / access tokens expiring in an iOS app design and have never really quite found a design that I am 100% comfortable with, so I am asking this here to see if anyone can come up with a better design than I currently use.

### The problem

You have an app that logs in with a username and password. The server returns an access token that should be used for future requests to authenticate that user. At some point in the future (unknown time) the server will expire that token and any request sent with that token will return an authentication failure.

After failure due to the session expiring, the app should re-login using the original credentials and get back a fresh access token. It can then retry the original request.

### Example

So imagine you have an API to get a list of news articles that requires authentication. The flow might go like this:

1. User logs in and app receives token.
2. View controller refreshes list of news articles.

   1. API request is made with token attached.
   2. API request successful and view is updated with new articles.
3. App is closed and some time passes.
4. App is opened at which point the view controller wants to refresh the list of news articles.

   1. API request is made with token attached.
   2. API request is unsuccessful because token has expired.
   3. View controller requests a refresh of the token and waits patiently.
   4. Once token has been refreshed, API request is retried.

Now imagine that this is done from more than one place in the app.

### How I currently solve it

What I usually do is store the credentials in `NSUserDefaults` (if I am not concerned with security of those credentials - obviously better to be using the keychain) and then have a method on a global manager object (singleton) which refreshes the login using these credentials when I notice that the session has expired. This global manager fires off notifications when the login state changes so that other parts of the app can know when they should retry a request after failure due to the session expiring.

### What I don't feel is right

Well, I just never have liked the state machine handling of the manager object. Every place that performs a request needs to save some state to know that a login refresh is going on and to retry the request after the login has been refreshed. There's also the problem of what to do if the refresh fails because the password is wrong now (the user changed it maybe) - you probably don't want to log out completely and destroy all user state of the app, because you might just be able to ask for the new password and carry on as before. But the global manager doesn't really relate to UI so it's hard to it to handle the UI of asking for the new login.

### What I want to know in answers

I understand that this question is particularly vague and conceptual (I still think it's OK to be on StackOverflow though?) but I'd really just like to know how other people solve this kind of problem. Just an explanation of how you go about handling the session expiration, retrying the failed requests from all over the app and asking the user for new credentials if refreshing didn't work.

I guess the crux of the whole thing is this question:

Where to put the retry logic of requests that failed due to session expiring. I see these places are options:

1. At the view controller level (i.e. keep a flag to say we need to retry the last request once login refresh has finished).
2. At the API request level (i.e. encapsulate the API request in an object that knows to retry after the login has been refreshed).
3. At the global login manager level (i.e. perhaps take a block in when `refreshLogin` is called that is executed once the login has been refreshed).

Comment: Curious about this as well, I've thrown around the idea (in my head) of using a separate `UIWindow` for the login screen. This way I can present it at any given point in the app without trashing the view lifecycle or worrying about handeling the presentation of the login view modally from any given view controller. Another thought was to sub-class `UIViewController` and have method to handle presentation of the login view at any given time, then use that sub-class for all view controllers. Both just feel a little "hacky" though. Have you made any headway on this?

Comment: Hey Chris! Sadly, no. It's still a pattern I've not solved entirely and remains a tricky one! There probably isn't a silver bullet right now :-(.

Comment: I just finished implementing the `UIWindow` route and it seems to be working good for now.

Answer (score 6):

Not to raise this question from the dead, but since it hasn't been answered I'll give my input.

What I chose to do for this scenario was to store the creds in the keychain (or wherever, really), and then I subclassed an HTTPClient to check whether to refresh or not before every call. This way, I can identify a refresh is needed, perform it, and retry the call all in one step as well as being able to send an error block up the chain if necessary to handle any cases in which the user could NOT be refreshed accordingly.

This seems to be in line with what you are (or probably were) trying to accomplish. No need for notifications or any of that jazz, and you can write it once and reuse it throughout the entire app by sending your calls through that subclassed HTTPClient.

EDIT: Bear in mind, you should remember to allow any authentication calls to pass!

Answer (score 2):

What you've asked is how to deal with session expiration. The others have answered your question. But I think you're asking the wrong question. Let me explain.

What we want is a design pattern for user sessions on iOS. We need to look at it from the point of view of the iOS device:

1. User installs the app
2. User authenticates with details and a session token is returned
3. The app then stores the (secret) session token on the device
4. Any future requests include the session token

Conclusion: **Any API designed for iOS shouldn't expire the session token.** It's simply kept secret on the device.

So from my experience the answer to your question about a design pattern for session expiration is basically:
Do not use session expiration when using an API for iOS.

[One of the biggest iOS REST API](https://www.parse.com/questions/question-about-sessiontoken-and-expiration-lack-there-of)'s out there is doing it this way, and I would have to agree.

Comment: your point of view may be wrong as there are regulations around the world for API and data handling. For instance, in the USA, medical data handling through API should have a session expiry to improve security.

Comment: Session expiry has to be there. What if the password to authenticate has been changed by the user!. In which case user has to re-login to the app with the new pwd, and this is when the session could be said 'Expired'

Answer (score 0):

You are mentioning two things in your question which seem key to answering it:

A) the app is in a state with data that could be lost if the user is not logged in.
B) the app needs to log back in to save the data.

If these are the constraints you should work around them accordingly:

1. Devise a scheme in which you can save changes locally. Keep track of the syncing state with the server.
2. If login status changes and something unexpected happens, unobtrusively alert the user and give her the opportunity to fix it.

Comment: Thanks @Mundi. Not quite what I had in mind though. It's nothing to do with local data needed to be synced up to the server. I've added in an example which should explain it more.

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view, the correct place to put you logic is in the View Controller level.

If I correctly understood you question, you have a Network API that handles the server calls and return the result (possibly from a JSON) to the view controller.

The best approach should be to create a Login View Controller, with the username/email and password fields, separate from the rest of the application logic. After receiving the OK from the server, this view controller can be dismissed and the application will flow as intended.

If your token was invalidated, the server should return an Error 401 to your Network API.
You can simply encapsulate that error into an `NSError` object, and pass to the View Controller to handle.

Anywhere in the app, a server call can return Error 401, and as a result you apologize to your user and pull back the Login View Controller, to force a new token to be created.

I hope I helped.

Comment: This works if we handle our API responses in the viewControllers. But for most of the applications out there, the network layer is segregated and there is no way other than passing the error back to each VC that called the service and handle it in each respective VC. :/

Answer (score 0):

My approach is similar to your '(2) At the API request level' - except rather than encapsualting the request in an object, encapsulate the whole concept of the API server.

Therefor I usually end up wrapping each type of request with an async method signature like this:

(Sorry, its C#, not obj-c (I use Xamarin.iOS) but the concept is the same - `Action<T>` is equivalent to obj-c [Blocks](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/index.html))

```
void GetLatestNews(GetLatestRequest request, Action<NewsListingResponse> success, Action<Exception> error)
void Search(SearchRequest request, Action<SearchResponse> success, Action<Exception> error)
```

I usually just make these static methods on a static class (very rarely will there be more than 1 server of the same type so a single static class will work fine) but I do sometimes put them within a singleton instance class so that I can pass in a mocked instance for unit tests.

Anyway, now your VC client code just consumes the api as needed:

```
override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
{
    SomeNewsSiteApi.GetLatestNews( new GetLatestRequest{Count=20}, 
        response =>
        {
            // Update table view here
        },
        error =>
        {
            // Show some error alert
        });
}
```

The beauty of this is that the implementation of those methods handle sending the request with the current token, and if it fails, obtains a new token, and then resends the same request with the new token, only then finally calling back into the `Action<T> success` callback. The client VC code has no idea about any re-obtaining of tokens, all it knows and cares about is that it is making a request for some data, and waiting for either a response or an error.

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same issue from couple of months. My approach '(2) At the API request level'

Please let me know if you got the best solution to resolve this.
That will really help many people who are facing these issues.

refresh the auth token when session expire is very big solution.