# Handling iOS HTTPRequest with session expire

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection

I've developed an app that request a token to do all the HTTPRequest.
I'm handling all the 100 different requests in a class called `NVEngine` where I'm calling Them like:

```
- (void) sendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)theRequest withRequestType:(NVRequestType)requestType {    
   NVURLConnection *conn = [[NVURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest 
                                                        delegate:self
                                                     requestType:requestType];

   if (!conn) {     
    NVLog(@"+++++++++++++++++++++++ UNABLE TO CREATE CONNECTION");      
   }
}
```

The problem is that the result of this request can be "session expired", and in this case I have to do a re-authentication http request to refresh token and then re-call the same previous request without an user interaction. How can i manage a callBack on my `sendRequest` method? from the `- (void) parseResultForConnection:(NVURLConnection *)connection` one? If I can return on `sendRequest` , I can firstly do a Synchronous request to retrieve a new token, and then retry my previous HTTPCall.

PS: I've already seen some answers on this topic like [Session expire design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906965/session-expire-design-pattern)
but I didn't find what's exactly I'm looking for.

Comment: Did you try to implement `NSURLConnectionDelegate` and/or `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`?

Comment: parseResultForConnection is already an implementation of delegate, I don't understand you question. Can you be more specific? :)

Comment: OK, you are using a custom class which not even google is aware of. So nobody will be able to help you in how to use it. But, usually, you would just parse the received data at `connectionDidFinishLoading:`, and if you received `session expired`, you would just send a new request to get a new token and retry the previous connect. When using `NSURLConnection` that is

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. but my question is: how can I resend the same request after token authentication without user interaction? Imagine that I've 100 different request spreaded in 20 viewcontroller, I need a pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

1. You are sending requests, I'm supposing asynchronously.
2. One of the request receive a `session expired`.
3. You set a static variable, for example `static BOOL isRetrievingNewToken` to `YES`. You create a static queue with blocks to call after the new token has been received, you initialize it with the request call that received `session expired`. If a new request is receive while `isRetrievingNewToken==YES`, you put it on the queue. If another request receives `session expired`, you put it on the queue.
4. When you receive the new token, you execute all blocks on the queue, remove the items, and set `isRetrievingNewToken` to `NO`.

Depending on how it looks like, it may be a good idea to implement this behavior in your connection class `NVURLConnection`.

Comment: the problem is that if I do the request with `NSURLConnection initWithRequest:delegate:`, how can retrieve the original request re retry It after the token request?

Comment: if you use `NSURLConnection` you can retrieve the original request by calling `connection.currentRequest`, where `connection` is the `NSURLConnection *` object (which is sent in most delegate methods)